# Angular Directive, argument not beign read and console.log not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm trying to make this directive work, the goal is to read a JSON object that comes with the menues text to display, according to it the tabs will fill with other directives.

**HTML**

```
<lista-tabs myMenues="general.sectionsList"></lista-tabs>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive('listaTabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myMenues: '@',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log("Inside link function");
            console.log(myMenues);
        },
    };
});
```

The other directives work just fine. I need to analyze that JSON object and according to it, assemble the menu, that won't be a problem once I get this working. But console.log is not showing anything, not even that plain text. The alert method works fine.

I have the console.log plugin for phonegap installed and works in other parts of the project.

BTW: I'm working in phonegap with tw bootstrap.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try changing your '@' to be a '=', also your second log should be console.log(scope.myMenues);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All angular directives need to be dash delimitted and i understand from your code that you want to bind this to an object to not a string, also you forgat to use scope on myMenues attr, here working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('stack', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.general = {
    sectionsList: 'someText'
  }
});

app.directive('listaTabs', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      myMenues: '=',
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log("Inside link function");
      alert(scope.myMenues);
    },
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="stack" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <lista-tabs my-menues="general.sectionsList"></lista-tabs>
</body>
```

Comment: console.log is not working on my project unless I put it inside a timeout. That way I verified that the menues are showing. Thank you very much @JsIsAwesome. I'll try to find out why I need a timeout to show the console.log inside link function.

Comment: If you make a fiddle to your full problem i will try to help.

Comment: Thanks, but it's part of a much larger project so I can't paste it all. I'll figure it out, thanks anyways (:

Answer (score 1):

The attributes of your directive (in the HTML) [follow the same angular normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes).  This means that they must be dash-delimitted just like the directive name.

```
<lista-tabs my-menues="general.sectionsList"></lista-tabs>
```

On another note, in your link function, you refer to a variable `myMenues`, which is not defined anywhere.  Remember that `myMenues is a property of your`scope`object you defined above.  You should be using`scope.myMenues`.

Finally, you are currently using the `@` binding, which is meant to bind to DOM strings.  If you actually want objects, you need to use either two-way `=` binding or a one-way expression binding (`&`).  See the [documentation for directive definitions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object).